# Find customer who placed order every month and who did not place order every month

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a query than can list the customers

1. who placed order every month form the following table? A: 123
2. who did not place an order every month? A:everyone except 123

   [image]

I am not proficient in such codes and I tried build sub-queries and cte's but I am not able to build my logic. I tried the following but not able to progress.

```
; with cte as(
SELECT customer_id,DATEPART(MONTH,Customer) as month,count(units) as no_of_order
from dwqc.dbo.orders
group by customer_id,DATEPART(MONTH,Customer))
select * from cte
```

Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: Break your problem into pieces. Step 1 - define (in words) what "every month" actually means. Your sample spans 3 months of last year. Very simply, no client has an order every month unless you limit the time frame. Once you have a time frame (beginning date, ending date), you know the total number of months.

Comment: You're counting people that placed an order every _month_. So you need to count distinct months. So you should add `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(MONTH,Customer))=3` to the end

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_id 
from dwqc.dbo.orders
group by customer_id 
having count(distinct DATEPART(MONTH,Customer))
     = (select count(distinct DATEPART(MONTH,Customer)) from dwqc.dbo.orders)
```

Thanks @Nick.McDermaid